# how we add watermark on image which is captured using webcam in wpf?

Tags: wpf

How do I add a watermark to webcam image that is saved in the following routine:

```
 public static void SaveImageCapture(BitmapSource bitmap)
    {
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

        encoder.QualityLevel = 100;

        // Configure save file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Image"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".Jpg"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Image (.jpg)|*.jpg"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Save Image
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            encoder.Save(fstream);
            fstream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This gentlemen had a similar problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8245dafc-ff74-4c3c-9ad7-156c8d2e97e5/watermark-merging-jpegs-in-wpf

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you look for answers? What didn't work as expected and why?

Comment: i had already solved my issue.

Comment: i dnt need to tell what is not wrking and why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method draws a text on top of a BitmapSource and returns the whole thing as a new BitmapSource, which you could pass to your save method.

You have to play around with font, size, and position of the `FormattedText` object. Please consult the MSDN documentation for all the details. Put special attention to the `DrawingContext` documentation to get an idea of your options.

```
public BitmapSource AddWatermark(BitmapSource image, string watermarkText)
{
    var text = new FormattedText(
        watermarkText,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("Segoe UI"),
        14,
        Brushes.White);

    var visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        drawingContext.DrawImage(image, new Rect(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
        drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(0, 0));
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight,
                                        image.DpiX, image.DpiY, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    return bitmap;
}
```